# a simple (i think) REGEX needed for Textmate

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

Can someone please advise how to do this search and replace in textmate. I think I need a REGEX  (but i know very little about REGEXes!)

i want to change all these bullet images to GIFs...

**bullet-1.png**

becomes

**bullet-1.gif**

and I want where the number is to be a wildcard

Comment: Perhaps [read a tutorial on regex](http://regular-expressions.info/)?

Comment: @Nightfirecat, anything but [the most popular manuals](http://regular-expressions.info/) will help, at least I don't understand its regex explanations. My recommendation: google for _regular expression in perl tutorial_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
bullet-(\d+).png
```

The replacement:

```
bullet-$1.gif
```

Comment: even more "correct" would be `bullet-(\d+)\.png` but functionally identical in this case.

Comment: KillerX, true, though very unlikely a pattern without escaped dot char not to match correctly.